# Why scala 2.8 REPL does not auto-complete some method (i.e. forall, exists)?

Tags: scala, autocomplete, scala-2.8, read-eval-print-loop

I started the scala REPL an write the following code:

```
scala> val a = Array(1,2,3,4)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> a.`<TAB>`

asInstanceOf   getClass       isInstanceOf   toString

scala> a.exists(_ == 1)
res1: Boolean = true
```

`Why I don't have "exists" listed when I press <TAB>?`

Comment: Try with the latest nightly, this changeset may have fixed things: http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/21679

Answer (score 1):

I think it because Array do not have  'exists' method. 'exists' method is belong to ArrayOps.

Comment: The gap being bridged by an implicit conversion, making the code valid. And I think you mean `ArrayOps`, not `StringOps`.